# Bleeding damage vs increased critical for a blademaster?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In *Kingdoms of Amalur: Recoking* I'm building a faeblades/bow blademaster. I don't use any of the poison related abilities as I find them quite weak except for the top tier one. I also don't use the skill Enduring Agony. The way I understand it the thing about bleeding damage is not the damage itself but the weakening effect it has on enemies.

Both bow and faeblades are all about crit but should I have some bleeding damage on my faeblades or increase crit chance?

Here is the [Reckoning Ability Calculator](http://www.38watch.com/calculator/#0004500056506505560550000336063650030003450530600000000000000000000000000000) for my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found both poison and bleeding damage to be underwhelming until I reached the top tier of the finesse tree. The abilities that stun enemies with poison damage and do extra damage to bleeding enemies are pretty exceptional. Once you get these, I would suggest putting both poison and bleeding damage on your weapons.

I've kept my crit chance over at least 30%, and that seems plenty sufficient. You hit so many times with faeblades that you're going to get a crit or two on most enemies, assuming you don't just kill them outright with your first hit.